# Retrieving first of two values in Python dictionary

Tags: python

Here is the code I'm working with so far:

```
measures = {}

for i in range(3):

  if i == 0:
     measures[i] = [[C4, D4, E4], [.25, .25, .25]]
  elif i == 1:
     measures[i] = [[D4, E4, F4], [.50, .50, .50]] 
  else:
     measures[i] = [[E4, F4, G4], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]

a = choice(measures)
```

I want the for loop iterator to be my key (0,1,2) and the first and second lists to be my values.

When I ask the program to print `a`, I get one of the two list choices (`[[C4, D4, E4], [.25, .25, .25]]`, for example), but I want to retrieve only the first list from each choice (`[C4, D4, E4]`, for example).

How might I do this?

Comment: Append another index: `List[n][m]`

Comment: `a = choice(measures)[0]`?

Comment: Thanks Kevin. That did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

The way to go about this is to probably  set `a` to `choice(measures)`, and then iterate over that using a `for loop` setting `a[i]` to `a[i][0]`, therefore grabbing the first element. Your code might look a little something like this:

```
`measures = {}

for i in range(3):

  if i == 0:
    measures[i] = [[C4, D4, E4], [.25, .25, .25]]
  elif i == 1:
    measures[i] = [[D4, E4, F4], [.50, .50, .50]] 
  else:
    measures[i] = [[E4, F4, G4], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]

a = choice(measures)`

for i in a:

  a[i] = a[i][0] # set each element of a to the first element of that item

# use a down here
```